# Directory.CreateDirectory could not find a part of path c:\

Tags: c#, .net, create-directory

Why does Directory.CreateDirectory throw a DirectoryNotFoundException when attempting to create the following path?

```
"c:\\temp\\aips\\data\\prn"
```

with message indicating it `could not find a part of the path "c:\"`.

Yet, if passed the following path `"c:\\temp\\aips\\data\\power"`, it returns successfully.

The paths are copied directly from the Visual Studio debugger hence the back slash delimiters.

On my system, the folder `c:\temp\aips\data` already exists.

Comment: Do you mean DirectoryInfo.Create or Directory.CreateDirectory? There is no Directory.Create method.

Comment: right click on desktop and create new folder ...can you give it 'prn' name??

Comment: I meant Directory.CreateDirectory.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 29):

As [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) says in a comment `prn` is one of the reserved device names and it points to the [print device](http://www.easydos.com/print.html) in DOS.

[image: The specified device name is invalid]

so change your path to another name and don't use the following reserved names for the name of a file:

> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9

Comment: `com#`, `lpt#`, `aux`, `con`, and `nul` are other [reserved device names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Definitely not intuitive from the exception message.